# SQL Server : how to output one table result from multiple results from a WHILE loop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

I want to go through all the variables in a table, and get the proportion of missing values of each variable. In order to do this, first I retrieve the column names and position (I also get data_type because I want to exclude some variables with certain data types), and then I carry out a dynamic SQL with a WHILE query.

I'm trying to output all results from this WHILE query into one table. I have tried doing this by creating a temporary table first.

Here is my code:

```
-- Create a temporary table before while loop in which you 
-- can store the resulted records.
CREATE TABLE #TEMP 
( 
    COLUMN_NAME NVARCHAR(128), 
    N INT, 
    PCT FLOAT 
)

-- Retrieve list of column names I want to go through and their positions 
-- and data type from system table.
DECLARE @coltable TABLE
                  (
                       COLUMN_NAME NVARCHAR(128),  
                       ORDINAL_POSITION INT, 
                       DATA_TYPE NVARCHAR(128)
                  )

INSERT INTO @coltable (COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION, DATA_TYPE)
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION, DATA_TYPE
    FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Community_PLD' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DID';

-- Start WHILE loop

DECLARE @COUNTER INT
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @coltable;

DECLARE @X INT
SET @X = 3; --start from the third variable

DECLARE @colname NVARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @datatype NVARCHAR(128);

WHILE (@X <= @COUNTER)
BEGIN
     SELECT @colname = COLUMN_NAME, @datatype=DATA_TYPE 
     FROM @coltable 
     WHERE ORDINAL_POSITION = @X

     IF @datatype = 'date' 
         GOTO jump_to_counter --ignore anything with date as datatype
     ELSE 
         INSERT INTO #TEMP (COLUMN_NAME, N, PCT)
              EXEC ('SELECT ' + @colname + ', COUNT(*) AS N, (COUNT(*)/11757913.0)*100 AS PCT FROM [DID].[Community_PLD] GROUP BY ' + @colname + ' ORDER BY PCT DESC')

     SET @X = @X + 1

jump_to_counter:
     SET @X = @X + 1
END
GO

SELECT * FROM #TEMP;
DROP TABLE #TEMP;
```

The problem is:

I simply end with the temporary table empty when it should have thousands of lines.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Rather than a while loop, dynamic sql, and a temp table, all of which are things to avoid like the plague in sql, this might be a job for a recursive CTE, or maybe even just a self join.

Comment: Add some `PRINT`s for debug purpose - see what's happening when you run this code. Also I suggest you to get rid of `GOTO` (this is extremely simple to update this code to get rid of it) and remove `ORDER BY` - it hits performance and makes no sense since there is no column or anything to save computed order and it won't affect final resultset (even no clustered index, no identity on # table).

Comment: And actually you did not initialize `@COUNTER` )

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space  or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Thank you, I was able to get an output after getting rid of `GOTO`, `ORDER BY` and initialising the `@COUNTER`.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thank you I am new to SQL, transitioning over from SAS. I tried to write a recursive CTE, but couldn't quite work out how to do it as some item are not allowed e.g. `GROUP BY`

Comment: @HABO Thank you, it let me use `QUOTENAME()` on some items but not others... I'm not sure why but I have the desired output.